# Azure app config not returning latest updated/refreshed ALL values using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure

I am new to spring boot(Java technology). I have referred both manual refresh and auto refresh described on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-java-spring-app#use-automated-refresh However, it still cannot get the updated values in the app config when I hit the API from postman. I even set the refresh interval to 1s. This is the bootstrap.properties file.

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string=${APP_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING}
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.triggers[0].key=sentinel
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.refresh-interval=1s
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].feature-flags.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.feature-flag-refresh-interval=1s
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.watch-interval=1s
```

My App configuration contains multiple feature flags(key's) but as I mentioned above bootstrap file added key as **"sentinel"** able to get the latest value for that key.

Any idea how I can configure all keys which present in app configuration and if any of the key value gets updated in app config it should return that updated value. Currently if I add spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.triggers[0].key=*  its returning all keys with old values and if I provide any specific key name then only that specific key getting refreshed value along with all key old value.

Can anyone please suggest how I can configure all keys for refresh monitoring triggers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can someone please help on this issue?